# Why does pandas.DataFrame.apply produces Series instead of DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I do not really understand why from the following code pandas return is Series but not a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,9]]*3, columns = ["A", "B"])

def plus_2(x):
    y =[]
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        y.append(x[i]+2)
    return y

df_row = df.apply(plus_2, axis = 1) # Applied to each row
df_row
```

While if I change `axis=0` it produces DataFrame as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,9]]*3, columns = ["A", "B"])

def plus_2(x):
    y =[]
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        y.append(x[i]+2)
    return y

df_row = df.apply(plus_2, axis = 0) # Applied to each row
df_row
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In first example where you put **axis=1** you implement on row level.
It means that for each row **plus_2** function returns **y** which is list of two element (but list as a whole is single element so this is pd.Series).
Based on your example it will be returned 3x list (2 element each). Here single list if single row.

You could expand this result and create two columns (each element from list will be new column) by adding **result_type="expand"** in apply:

```
df_row = df.apply(lambda x: plus_2(x), axis=1, result_type="expand")

# output

    0   1
0   6   11
1   6   11
2   6   11
```

In second approach you have **axis=0** co this is applied on column level.
It means that for each column **plus_2** function returns **y**, so **plus_2** is applied twice, separately for A column and for B column. This is why it returns dataframe: your input is DataFrame with columns A and B, each column applies plus_2 function and returns A and B columns as result of plus_2 functions applied.

Based on your example it will be returned 2x list (3 element each). Here single list is single column.

So the main difference between axis=1 and axis=0 is that:

if you applied on row level **apply** will return:

```
[6, 11]
[6, 11]
[6, 11]
```

if you applied on column level **apply** will return:

```
[6, 6, 6]
[11, 11, 11]
```